# Поиск грамотного решения по SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет, представим, что есть таблица матчей со следующими столбцами: дата, команда хозяев, команда гостей, количество голов хозяев, количество голов гостей. В каждом матче необходимо вывести голы за последние 5 матчей команды хозяев и голы за последние 5 матчей команды гостей (всего 10 дополнительных столбцов). Я решаю это следующим образом:

1. Делаю вывод даты, команды хозяев, количества голов хозяев, затем через union объединяю с выводом даты, командой гостей и количеством голов гостей.
2. В получившемся результате через оконную функцию вывожу интересующие данные по голам в последних 5 играх.
3. Джойню итоговый результат к основной таблице.
   Собственно вопрос, существует ли более аккуратный способ решения? Такой, чтобы не громоздить подзапросы; что-то вроде оконной функции, осуществляющей поиск по 2 столбцам (в данном случае хозяев и гостей) с выводом соответствующего результата (голы хозяев или гостей).

Comment: Это функция [`LAG()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

Comment: Это естественно, она используется вместе с оконной функцией. Хотел бы понять, возможно ли избавиться от объединения.

Comment: При использовании оконной функции всё выполняется на одной копии таблицы, никаких объединений не требуется.